# Just published apk crashes on asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

i have just now published my app on google play store. I'm sure that the apk is well written and compiled, without any crashes. Unfortunally after i've published it on the store in beta-version it crashes on the FIRST asynctask. This is my log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at it.mybow.SaronnoCity.Login.RegStep3$Senddata.doInBackground(RegStep3.java:358)
at it.mybow.SaronnoCity.Login.RegStep3$Senddata.doInBackground(RegStep3.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

And this is the class of the mysterious error:

```
class Senddata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Registrazione in corso...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int success;
        MyApplication application;
        application = (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext();

      //String regId = application.getGCMId();      
        String regId = "Appenaregistrato";
        String nome = application.getnome();
        String sesso = application.getsesso();
        String email = application.getemail();
        String username = application.getusername();
        String password = application.getpassword();
        String telefono = application.gettelephone();
        //Log.d("regId", regId);

        try {
            Log.d("regId", regId);
            Log.d("nome", nome);
            Log.d("sesso", sesso);
            Log.d("email", email);
            Log.d("username", username);
            Log.d("password", password);
            Log.d("telefono", telefono);


        //Aggiungo i parametri generati dalle variabili
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_id", regId));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nome", nome));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sesso", sesso));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telefono", telefono));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Utilizzo JSON per mandare i dati delle variabili
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);


            // Line 358 ERROR
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            //Se va tutto bene... 
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 3) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                getActivity().finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }if(success == 0){
                Log.d("Inserire tutti i campi!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("L'username scelto è gia in uso", json.toString());

                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }if(success == 2){
                Log.d("Operazione fallita!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //Funzione dismiss
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

};
```

So two thinks make all this very strange:
1) why does my app crash after been published, while the apk does not?
2) why it crashes not on a specific asyntask, but in general on the first called?

Thanks to all.

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: please dont parse Json in doInBackground , parse everything in onPostExecute

Comment: Why is that, @TusharPandey ?

Comment: or dont use getActivyt().finish() in doInBackGround()

Comment: I am not sure, but it can be the problem of getActivity(). I think it is returning NULL on that phone.

Comment: @TusharPandey it carshes at this line `Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());`(see his question) so why he should remove everything out of `doInBackground`. Rather than making a guess everytime i would Focus on the real Problem...

Comment: @Vivek getActivity() is very unlikely to return null on certain devices and not others. Besides, if getActivity() indeed returned null, the app would have crashed in onPreExecute, which is also making use of that method...

Comment: How is jsonParser initialized ? Could makeHttpRequest return null if the request is not successful (in which case calling toString on the result causes a crash) ?

Comment: @2Dee,you are right. I just want to add one more point. Some null check is missing. At runtime null could create a problem.

Comment: @Vivek, I really don't understand what you mean, what null check ? The AsyncTask should only be started after the Fragment's Activity is fully created, so there shouldn't be any need for checking if getActivity() returns null, because it shouldn't if you handled lifecycle callbacks properly...

Comment: So, what do you suggest? Why crashes only on google store app?